# Trackable Entities with edmx (2 dbcontext) issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hi in my project I want to use [Trackable Entities - N-Tier Support for Entity Framework with WCF](https://github.com/TrackableEntities/trackable-entities)

i am stuck with the problem:

after i add the edmx with all my tables i get stuck with 2 DbContext

one from the template that I need to use for making the entities trackable

```
EFModelFromDatabase\Context.cs.t4
```

and one that i get when i add the edmx

```
Models\MyData.edmx that contains Context.tt
```

how can I (if it's possible to merge the context to the t4 format)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer :

To generate trackable service entities from the EDM diagram, right-click on the design surface of the model and select “Add Code Generation Item”.

From there you can select which database objects to include.  Then expand the Trackable, Data category and select “Service Trackable Entities EF 6.x Model First Generator”. For the name enter the same model name you specified when adding the EDM to your project.